# Passing parameters to get request in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to create a link to a page in django via a GET request. But, I have to pass the value of a parameter. How do I do so?

urls.py

```
path('questions/<int:user_id>/', views.recommendationquestions,{'template_name':'questions.html'}, name = 'questions'),
```

answers.html

```
<a href="{% url 'questions' {{rlist.0.userId}} %}">Rate more movies</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest `{%` and `{{`. With `{%` your variables are available without the need of `{{`. Your code should be:

```
<a href="{% url 'questions' user_id=rlist.0.userId %}">Rate more movies</a>
```

also note the `user_id=` because your URL parameter is named.